# Batch Configuration not worked .What's the issue?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

What is an issue in above code??
Where I have to change to make code run successfully.
Do I need to change anything

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration 
{
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        System.out.println("here1");
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource =new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ssk");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("hardik0000007");
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<people> reader()
    {
        System.out.println("here2");
        FlatFileItemReader<people> reader =new FlatFileItemReader<people>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("employeeData.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<people>(){{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer(){{
                setNames(new String[]{"fname","lname"});
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<people>(){{
                setTargetType(people.class);
            }});
        }});

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessor processor()
    {
        System.out.println("here3");
        return new UserItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<people> writer()
    {
        System.out.println("here4");
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<people> writer =new JdbcBatchItemWriter<people>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<people>());
        writer.setSql("Insert into people (first_name,last_name) values (:fname,:lname)");  
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);   
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1()
    {
        System.out.println("here5");
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<people,people> chunk(3).
            reader(reader()).
            processor(processor()).
            writer(writer())
            .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob()
    {
        System.out.println("here6");
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob").
                incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).
                flow(step1()).
                end().
                build();

    }


}
```

Partial Log Output:

```
c.e.demo.SpringBatchBootdemoApplication : Starting SpringBatchBootdemoApplication on Sony-PC
c.e.demo.SpringBatchBootdemoApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default 
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigAppli‌​cationContext@ceda24‌​: startup date
o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup c.e.demo.SpringBatchBootdemoApplication : Started SpringBatchBootdemoApplication in 1.254 seconds (JVM running for 1.837) 
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigAppli‌​cationContext@ceda24‌​: startup date 
o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter
```

Comment: Can you please specify what error you are facing. Like the stack trace. Does the job start at all?

Comment: Code is running without any error.
But desire output not getting.

Comment: c.e.demo.SpringBatchBootdemoApplication  : Starting SpringBatchBootdemoApplication on Sony-PC 
c.e.demo.SpringBatchBootdemoApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@ceda24: startup date

Comment: o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
c.e.demo.SpringBatchBootdemoApplication  : Started SpringBatchBootdemoApplication in 1.254 seconds (JVM running for 1.837)
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@ceda24: startup date
o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter

Comment: I think this file is not scanned and reason behind the code contain in this file not being executed

Comment: could you also add the maven configuration? your pom.xml

Comment: Make sure the BatchConfiguration class is in the same package or subpackage as the SpringBatchBootdemoApplication class.